# MUI TablePagination, what are "ActionComponent" vs "Component" props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

According to the MUI documentation --> https://mui.com/api/table-pagination/#main-content,

`ActionComponent = The component used for displaying the actions. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.`,

`Component = The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component`,

After looking at the description above, I am still confused what they exactly mean.

What does "displaying the action" mean in "ActionComponent" ?

What does "component used for the root node" imply in "Component"?

Can I have some solid example to demonstrate how "ActionComponent" and "Component" props are used?

Or a reference to related resources please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`component` is for the root, the container of the whole `TablePagination` component. Example for use: https://mui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting - you see that the pagination component is defined as `div`. It overrides the default `td` to be rendered correctly outside the `Table`.

`ActionComponent` lets you override the inner component of navigation buttons inside the root `TablePagination` component. Great example for this: https://mui.com/components/tables/#custom-pagination-actions.